# :checked not working in css

Tags: php, html, css

*Context:*

I've been working on the front and back-end for a fun startup company for the last month. There is a profile page on the website for users who are logged in. As shown below in its default state:

**Default state**

[image]

Using the 'checkbox' hack / trick, by clicking on the setting icon (as referenced through the label tag in the css below) The logged in user can open a side menu, with settings and options for their account as shown below:

**The menu expanded**

[image]

*The problem:*

Clicking on the profile text is supposed to create a drop-down menu so that the user can upload their own profile picture. I was hoping to do this through the same checkbox hack as before. **However, when clicking on the profile text (referenced as h1), the checkbox is ticked but the background (referenced as .sidebar h1) doesn't change its colour to red.** I think this is because of a problem with the :checked function in css, because when I click on the profile text I can see the checkbox become checked and unchecked.

*Of note:*

1. I can use javascript, but it's really not preferable (the person I'm working for isn't a big fan.)
2. Here is the whole file: https://pastebin.com/E0H6HgRe

**CSS**

```
.sidebar {
    background-color: white; 
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 0; 
    bottom: 0; 
}
input#slide-sidebar[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none; 
}



input#slide-sidebar:checked ~ .sidebar{
left: 0; 
width: 201; 
z-index: 3;
-webkit-transition: width 2s; 
transition: width 2s; 
}

.setting {
    font-size: 100px;
    color:black;
    z-index: 0;
    background-color:white;
    position: fixed;
    left: 18.8%;
    width: 100%;
}

input#slide-sidebar:not(:checked) ~ .sidebar {
    width: 0;  
    -webkit-transition: width 2s; 
    transition: width 2s; 
}

h1{
    color: #222; 
    font-size: 20;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color:black;
    left: 0px;
    opacity:0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 200px;
}

input#slide-sidebar:checked ~ .sidebar h1 {
    opacity: 1; 
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in;
}

input#slide-sidebar:not(:checked) ~ .sidebar h1 {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease-out; 
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-out;
}
input#profile-pic:checked ~ .sidebar h1 {
background-color: red; 
}
```

**Php (html running inside php)**

```
echo "<div class='main-wrap'><input id='slide-sidebar' type = 'checkbox' role='button' /> <label for='slide-sidebar' class='setting'><span><i class = 'fa fa-cog'></i></span></label><div class='sidebar'>

<input id='profile-pic' type = 'checkbox' role='button' /><label for='profile-pic'><span><h1> Profile</h1></span></label></div>";
```

Comment: The bottommost CSS selector is not valid: the div with class `sidebar` does not follow the input with id `profile-pic`.